# Configure apache to serve correct content rather than using symbolic links

Tags: apache-2.2

**Background:**

I have many domains and subdomains pointed at my server via HTTPS (on unique IPs). There's a redirect on the root to redirect them to a directory based on the first part of the domain name (legacy system didn't used to use subdomains)

`https://foo.example.com/` redirects to `https://foo.example.com/foo` and `https://customdomain.com/` redirects to `https://customdomain.com/customdomain`

All this works fine and I'm happy with it. Ultimately these URLs can't change.

**Here's what I'm looking for help with:**

Currently in the global `DocumentRoot` used by all domains is a symbolic link to a version controlled release which can be different for each domain (https://zap.example.com/zap will serve version 1.2.0):

```
foo -> /path/to/release/1.2.3
bar -> /path/to/release/1.2.3
zap -> /path/to/release/1.2.0
```

This means that https://foo.example.com/foo will ultimately be served release/1.2.3.

This all works JUST FINE. However I feel that maintaining this using symbolic links is messy and is something that Apache could handle for me in a simple config file. And that I can then sync that config file across multiple servers.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how I could do this?

- I certainly don't want to redirect and serve http://foo.example.com/1.2.3.
- I don't mind a config file that's just hundreds of <virtualhost> directives if that's what it takes .. as it would be machine generated and maintained.

Comment: `as it would be machine generated and maintained`: What prevents you from maintaining this links automatically? Just for this very limited and specific purpose, I don't see an advantage (nor a disadvantage) from handling this in the Apache config files - you can automate it either way.

Answer (score 1):

First if you don't already have, you need one vhost definition by domain (can be in the same file but seperate files is better for clarity).

Then from that point you can't really escape the symlink need, but a cleaner way to do it would be to point all your vhost to a symlink called current that point to your current /path/to/release/x.x.x.

Then when you deploy a new version you just change the current symlink, this keep your url clean and is more easy to know that you are pointing to the current release rather than a folder called foo.

Vhost example would be:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName foo.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/foo/current
    ....
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName bar.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bar/current
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

Where current points:

/var/www/html/foo/current -> /var/www/html/foo/release/x.x.x

/var/www/html/bar/current -> /var/www/html/bar/release/x.x.x

Hope it helps.

Comment: That doesn't get me anywhere except that I've replaced obvious versions with something called 'current' that hides the version. Each domain can have its own version, we don't upgrade them all at once. The aim of the question is to get rid of the per-domain symbolic link. I'm happy with the rest of the setup.

Comment: Then you have to checkout your code directly into your DocumentRoot.

This does not offer the same flexibility as with a symlink but will achieve what you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this within your Apache config would be:

```
Alias /foo /path/to/release/1.2.3
```

But the level of effort required to swap that config out (then run a graceful restart of the Apache service) is no easier than swapping out some symlinks, as Sven mentioned in his comment.

What you really need here is a configuration management tool like Puppet or Chef - these tools can easily manage either the symlinks or the `Alias`es, and have the same configuration applied across multiple servers with a simple, central configuration.